# Ordering the layers as baselayer,wms layer,tile layer based on z-index

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Before i was using Openlayer instance to create base layer and tile layer,and in openlayer has option to maitain index using z-index property to show tile layers on top of base layers,but in Mapbox GL didn't find any z-index property to avoid hiding one layer behind the other layer.

I used satellite map as base layer and one vector layer,but satellite base layer covering vector layer,and vector layer is getting hided.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add a 3D model</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src='https://unpkg.com/three@0.102.0/build/three.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.102.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA';
var map = window.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
    zoom: 17.5,
    center: [148.9819, -35.3981],
    pitch: 60
});

// parameters to ensure the model is georeferenced correctly on the map
var modelOrigin = [148.98190, -35.39847];
var modelAltitude = 0;
var modelRotate = [Math.PI / 2, 0, 0];
var modelScale = 5.41843220338983e-8;

// transformation parameters to position, rotate and scale the 3D model onto the map
var modelTransform = {
    translateX: mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(modelOrigin, modelAltitude).x,
    translateY: mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(modelOrigin, modelAltitude).y,
    translateZ: mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(modelOrigin, modelAltitude).z,
    rotateX: modelRotate[0],
    rotateY: modelRotate[1],
    rotateZ: modelRotate[2],
    scale: modelScale
};

var THREE = window.THREE;

// configuration of the custom layer for a 3D model per the CustomLayerInterface
var customLayer = {
    id: '3d-model',
    type: 'custom',
    renderingMode: '3d',
    onAdd: function(map, gl) {
        this.camera = new THREE.Camera();
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create two three.js lights to illuminate the model
        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        directionalLight.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
        this.scene.add(directionalLight);

        var directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        directionalLight2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
        this.scene.add(directionalLight2);

        // use the three.js GLTF loader to add the 3D model to the three.js scene
        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf', (function (gltf) {
            this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
        }).bind(this));
        this.map = map;

        // use the Mapbox GL JS map canvas for three.js
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: map.getCanvas(),
            context: gl
        });

        this.renderer.autoClear = false;
    },
    render: function(gl, matrix) {
        var rotationX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), modelTransform.rotateX);
        var rotationY = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), modelTransform.rotateY);
        var rotationZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), modelTransform.rotateZ);

        var m = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);
        var l = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(modelTransform.translateX, modelTransform.translateY, modelTransform.translateZ)
            .scale(new THREE.Vector3(modelTransform.scale, -modelTransform.scale, modelTransform.scale))
            .multiply(rotationX)
            .multiply(rotationY)
            .multiply(rotationZ);

        this.camera.projectionMatrix.elements = matrix;
        this.camera.projectionMatrix = m.multiply(l);
        this.renderer.state.reset();
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        this.map.triggerRepaint();
    }
};

map.on('style.load', function() {
    map.addLayer(customLayer);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox GL JS doesn't really have any concept of a base layer, there are just layers. The order you addLayer affects which order they are drawn in, alternatively you can do `addLayer(layer, before)` to add the layer before another layer.